# How to get 'trades' resource from Coinbase API?

Tags: coinbase-api

I use **coinbase-node** and got transaction API response.

In this response, I can see something like:

```
{
      ...
      "created_at": "2019-04-21T13:58:12Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-04-21T13:58:12Z",
      "resource": "transaction",
      "resource_path": "/v2/accounts/68a42d04-2075-529c-8cd8-183cd148c45f/transactions/279db234-ca73-5e66-b70a-94502d44739e",
      "instant_exchange": false,
      "trade": {
        "id": "f4ff2d5d-07b7-5c2c-807d-7b98591b488a",
        "resource": "trade",
        "resource_path": "/v2/accounts/68a42d04-2075-529c-8cd8-183cd148c45f/trades/f4ff2d5d-07b7-5c2c-807d-7b98591b488a"
      },
      "details": {
        "title": "Converted to Bitcoin Cash",
        "subtitle": "Using BTC Wallet",
        "payment_method_name": "BTC Wallet"
      },
      ...
}
```

my goal is to find a way to get a `trade` by ID

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This post should help you.
[How to import conversions in coinbase api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56622382/how-to-import-conversions-in-coinbase-api)
At this moment it is impossible to get trades from API call, but you can construct object yourself using trade Id.