# How to import conversions in coinbase api?

Tags: coinbase-api

Right now coinbase supports so called "conversions" that allow to convert from one currency to another. For example, you can convert some of your BTC to XRP.

In CSV they return both buy & sell amount in Notes field:
Notes | Converted 0.27235696 BTC to 3,731.323138 XRP.

However, they only return buy amount of that conversion in apy /transactions endpoint:

```
{"id":"b...8","type":"trade","status":"completed",
"amount":{"amount":"3731.323138","currency":"XRP"},
"native_amount":{"amount":"1790.76","currency":"CAD"},
"description":null,
"...,
"instant_exchange":false,
"trade":{"id":"34...2",
    "resource":"trade","resource_path":"\/v2\/accounts\/e...\/trades\/..,."},
"details":{"title":"Converted to XRP","subtitle":"Using BTC Wallet","payment_method_name":"BTC Wallet"}};
```

I can't find any way to find how much bitcoin was sold for such conversion using api endpoints. 
There is also reference to account/*id*/trades endpoint, but it returns 404 to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem and found a way to do it. 
Every transaction that is a trade has "trade" property which has "id" property.
If you converted USDC into XRP, in the XRP transactions of the specific user you will have transaction which has "trade" property with "id" that is the same as the "id" from one of the USDC transactions "trade" property's "id".

```
trade:
id: "0dfc2e63-21e7-5b25-99d9-49863eb37887"
resource: "trade"
resource_path: "/v2/accounts/a4b1dc86-a813-572b-9978-d1f9c9ba53bc/trades/0dfc2e63-21e7-5b25-99d9-49863eb37887"
__proto__: Object
details:
title: "Converted from USD Coin"
subtitle: "Using USDC Wallet"
payment_method_name: "USDC Wallet"
```

```
trade:
id: "0dfc2e63-21e7-5b25-99d9-49863eb37887"
resource: "trade"
resource_path: "/v2/accounts/a4b1dc86-a813-572b-9978-d1f9c9ba53bc/trades/0dfc2e63-21e7-5b25-99d9-49863eb37887"
__proto__: Object
details:
title: "Converted to XRP"
subtitle: "Using USDC Wallet"
payment_method_name: "USDC Wallet"
```

Look at the trade id of the two transactions. They are the same.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER: it appears that the Coinbase response for a trade transaction doesn't provide the correct amounts that you'd see in the Coinbase API or other CSV reports. The "spot price" and fees don't match with what you'd be able to determine from looking at the independent transactions. The answer provided by Raskolnikov does solve this issue.**

The Coinbase API documentation appears to be lacking (or Coinbase isn't publicly documenting it), but there is a `/trades` endpoint which will give you more information about your trade transaction.

Also, the data in the transaction response is lying to you because the `trade.resource_path` results in a 404. If you strip the `/accounts/68a42d04-2075-529c-8cd8-183cd148c45f` from the URL of `trace.resource_path` property, you'll end up with `/v2/trades/f4ff2d5d-07b7-5c2c-807d-7b98591b488a`, which I did find to work. Alternatively, you can just construct the trade URI from the `trade.id` property.

As an example response, here is one of mine, with some information removed:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "created_at": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "display_input_amount": {
            "amount": "1.43",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "id": "d1feb056-2e42-4a7f-b310-807e189d2e26",
        "input_amount": {
            "amount": "0.02551020",
            "currency": "MLN"
        },
        "output_amount": {
            "amount": "0.02096069",
            "currency": "AVAX"
        },
        "exchange_rate": {
            "amount": "0.82165918",
            "currency": "AVAX"
        },
        "unit_price": {
            "target_to_fiat": {
                "amount": "68.22",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "target_to_source": {
                "amount": "1.21704963",
                "currency": "MLN"
            }
        },
        "fee": {
            "amount": "0.00",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "status": "completed",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "user_warnings": [],
        "applied_subscription_benefit": false,
        "fee_without_subscription_benefit": null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Watching Coinbase API from webapp I understand what endpoint you need to call:

Have to know base_id of crypto that you want to sell and base_id of crypto want to buy. You can know it by call GET "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/ /assets/prices?base=USD&filter=holdable&resolution=latest" and get from response the "base_id" of your currencies.

Make an order by calling POST "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/trade" with a request body in json like this:

{ 'amount': [amount that you want to convert], 'amount_asset': [currency of amount that you want to convert], 'amount_from': 'input', 'source_asset': ["base_id" of crypto that you want to sell], 'target_asset': ["base_id" of crypto that you want to buy] }

If previous POST "/trade" response code is 201, you have to get the "id" value of response's json and do a commit of your order by calling POST "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/trades/[id of json response of previous https://api.coinbase.com/v2/trade POST"]. If the response code of this POST commit is 201, your exchange is started and if there are not error in coinbase, your conversion is done!